# Infinite Loop When Collection Mapping With Dozer

Tags: java, collections, mapping, infinite-loop, dozer

I'm developing a project which uses BackboneJS in front-end and Java - Spring Core in back-end. I have a problem about mapping entity(domain) objects to DTO objects. I am getting an error message like that :

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.countdown.dto.CategoryDTO["countdownList"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.countdown.dto.CountdownDTO["category"]->.......

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "NAME_SURNAME", nullable = false)
    private String nameSurname;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "REGISTER_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Date registerDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Role role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "createUser")
    private List<Countdown> createCountdownList = new ArrayList<Countdown>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "updateUser")
    private List<Countdown> updateCountdownList = new ArrayList<Countdown>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "FOLLOWINGS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTDOWN_ID"))
    private List<Countdown> followings = new ArrayList<Countdown>();

    //Getters and setters..

}
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ROLE_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String roleName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
 }
```

**Countdown.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTDOWN")
public class Countdown implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "COUNTDOWN_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "COUNTDOWN_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String countdownName;

    @Column(name = "COUNTDOWN_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Date countdownDate;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(5000)")
    private String countdownDescription;

    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @JoinColumn(name = "CREATE_USER", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private User createUser;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Date createDate;

    @JoinColumn(name = "UPDATE_USER", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private User updateUser;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Date updateDate;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_USER_IP", nullable = false)
    private int createIP;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> followers = new ArrayList<User>();

}
```

**Category.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CATEGORY")
public class Category implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="CATEGORY_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_NAME" , nullable = false)
    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Countdown> countdownList = new ArrayList<Countdown>();

}
```

Business Logic : **CategoryServiceImpl.java** 
I'm getting error in forEach loop.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<CategoryDTO> getAllCategories() {
    List<Category> categoryList;
    List<CategoryDTO> categoryDTOList = new ArrayList<CategoryDTO>();

    logger.debug("getAllCategories called");

    try {
        categoryList = categoryDAO.findAll();
        for(Category category : categoryList){
            categoryDTOList.add(mapper.map(category,CategoryDTO.class));
        }
    }catch (NoResultException e){
        logger.error("getAllCategories method : No Category wasn't found");
        logger.warn(e,e);
    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("getAllCategories method : Categories wasn't found");
        logger.warn(e,e);
    }
    return categoryDTOList;
}
```

Also Do I have to use DTO object in Presentation Layer? Can I use entity objects in presentation layer instead of DTO objects?

How can I solve this problem? Sorry my bad english. Thank you!

Comment: if so please accept/vote it

Answer (score 1):

Please Try :

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<CategoryDTO> getAllCategories() {
        List<Category> categoryList;
        List<CategoryDTO> categoryDTOList = new ArrayList<CategoryDTO>();

        logger.debug("getAllCategories called");

        try {
            categoryList = categoryDAO.findAll();

            for(Category category : categoryList){
                  if(category.getCountdownList() != null && !category.getCountdownList().isEmpty()){
                      for(Countdown countdown : category.getCountdownList()){
                          countdown.setCategory(null);
                      }
                   }
                categoryDTOList.add(mapper.map(category,CategoryDTO.class));
            }
        }catch (NoResultException e){
            logger.error("getAllCategories method : Hata: No Category wasn't found");
            logger.warn(e,e);
        }catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("getAllCategories method : Hata: Categories wasn't found");
            logger.warn(e,e);
        }
        return categoryDTOList;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in if statement IDE cannot recognize category object.
http://imgur.com/IGFJN6t

Comment: I tried but I'm getting this error now:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "category_id" violates not-null constraint. 

I think we set null to an id column.

Comment: Please write stacktrace ?

Comment: I couldn't understand. I debugged the project. It seemed there is not a problem. Then I removed Transactional(readOnly=True) line. Now I got LazyInitialization exception :(
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11872966/

Answer (score 1):

For those who are struggling with infinite recursion issue in Dozer.

I use `mapId` to define a leaf object and stops the recursion.

Let assume we have two entities `Course` and `Teacher`, which contains a **Many-to-Many** relationship, and we want to convert the following object graph to one represented by `CourseDTO` and `TeacherDto`. And we hope **Dozer** stops at the 3rd level.

```
Teacher 1 ---> m Course 1 ---> m Teacher ---> ...
1st level        2nd level       3rd level
```

We can first define the following definition for `Teacher` to `TeacherDTO` conversion.

This first mapping is used for the root `Teacher` entity.
Include any other fields you need in the mapping.

```
mapping(Teacher.class, TeacherDTO.class,
                    TypeMappingOptions.oneWay()
                    , mapNull(false)
            ).fields("courses", "courses");
```

The following mapping will prevent Dozer from going further to map the contained `Course`. We define a mapId `teacherLeaf` for it.
Exclude the fields that cause the infinite recursion. (In my example, it's **courses**)
Include any other fields you need in the mapping.

```
                mapping(Teacher.class, TeacherDTO.class,
                    TypeMappingOptions.oneWay(), TypeMappingOptions.mapId("teacherLeaf")
                    , mapNull(false)
            ).exclude("courses");
```

The last one is the mapping rule for `Course` to `courseDTO`. The key is that we tell the mapper to use the `teacherLeaf` mapping rule defined previously to convert the contained `Teacher`s.

```
                mapping(Course.class, CourseDTO.class,
                    TypeMappingOptions.oneWay()
                    , mapNull(false)
            ).fields("teachers", "teachers", useMapId("teacherLeaf"));
```

Hope this helps!

I use Dozer 6.1.0.